# Portrait mode shows black screen on a browser in Unity Webgl, landscape opens fine

Tags: javascript, html, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I am using Unity version 2019.4.19f1 to make webgl build. After making the build I resize the unity canvas using these line below (in UnityLoader.js inside "DOMContentLoaded" eventlistner):

```
let unityContent = document.getElementById('unityContainer');
var tempWidth = window.innerWidth - ( window.innerWidth * 0.0001 );
var tempHeight = window.innerHeight;
unityContent.style.width = tempWidth+'px';
unityContent.style.height = tempHeight+'px';
```

But when I open this in a browser in Portrait mode I get a black screen, while when I open it in landscape mode then it is working fine. And this happens in devices having screen size 6 inches and above only. On devices having smaller height the portrait mode opens fine and no black screen is shown.

Also if I hard code the `tempHeight` to `1500px` then even portrait mode shows the canvas instead of black screen but then there is empty space on the screen above and below the canvas.
What's more troubling is that the same code was working fine a few months ago in other projects.

Can Anyone Help me out with this please? Have been stuck on this for some time now.

Answer (score 0):

Have you just tried setting the width and height to a 100% of screen and are able to reproduce the issue?

If it works with this, then your canvas is getting drawn outside the bounds, else there's something else wrong.

Comment: I have tried setting html and body to width and height 100%, yet I am having the same issue. Plus I am doing this on a separately new test project which I made just to test this out with no big gameobjects and code. This is happening in every project and every build now.